# RTF not opening into RichTextBox properly

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to open a .rtf into a Rich Text Box

Every time I open the file it puts this into the Rich Text Box:

http://pastebin.com/jwYwds9y [shows raw RTF]

This is my code to open:

```
Public Sub openFile()
    Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
    ofd.Filter = fileFilter
    ofd.FileName = ""
    Select Case ofd.ShowDialog()
        Case DialogResult.OK
            loadFile(ofd.FileName)
    End Select
End Sub
Public Sub loadFile(ByVal file As String)
    Try
        fileName = file
        setText(IO.File.ReadAllText(file))
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
Public Sub setText(ByVal value As String)
    Dim t As RichTextBox = tabH.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType(Of RichTextBox)().First()
    t.Text = value
End Sub
```

I have a tab control and there is no main textbox, when the app runs it uses code to add the first tab. Code:

```
Public Sub newFile()
    Dim t As New TabPage
    Dim p As New RichTextBox
    t.Text = "Untitled"
    p.Parent = t
    p.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    tabH.TabPages.Add(t)
    t.Visible = True
    AddHandler p.KeyDown, Sub(sn As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) makeChanged()
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `t.Rtf = value`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton you should write that as the answer, because that is most likely the solution.

Comment: @VisualVincent Sometimes it takes me time to think what I could usefully pad an otherwise very short answer with to add some value.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, pad your response with statement that the OP should use the [RichTextBox.LoadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f99sst7(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of creating their own implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `t.Rtf = value`.

Setting the `.Text` property enters the data verbatim, whereas setting the [`Rtf` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf(v=vs.110).aspx) causes it to parse the data as RTF.

You could also consider using the [RichTextBox.LoadFile Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f99sst7(v=vs.110).aspx).